# What is the best way to create a list of text and images, using JavaScript and little to no HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have successfully made a list using strictly `HTML` and `CSS` and that was simple enough. Now, I want to create the same list, while using `JavaScript`, for the most part. I'm not so sure why its so confusing for me.

Now I understand that in my HTML file, I must create a div for that list, and can implement the content in my `.js` file, while styling it however in my `.css` file. So here's what I have (and what I'm assuming is all I need) in my html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="content-list"></div>
</div>
```

I haven't really touched my css file yet because I like to save the styling for last. 
I have a bit of a starting point in my .js file but let me explain a few things before showing my meaningless code (which I wrote based off what I was trying to understand from other examples or tutorials, but didn't fully know what I was doing). All I want, is to display a list of my favorite movies, along with an image aligned next to each movie title. That's all! I don't plan on adding any elements later, or removing... I just want my list but I can't figure it out! I feel so dumb.

Anyway, here's what I have (and yes I'm including the part I had commented out because I'm not sure which way is better, and I apologize for not finishing what I started with):

```
// JavaScript Document

function myMovies (movieTitle, movieThumb) {
this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
this.movieThumb = movieThumb;
}

/**
var contentList = [
{'content_title':'District 9', 'img_src':'district9.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Gladiator', 'img_src':'gladiator.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Django Unchained', 'img_src':'django.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Fantastic Mr. Fox', 'img_src':'fox.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Master and Commander', 'img_src':'master.jpg', 'target_dir':''}
];
**/

myMovies.prototype.myMovies = function (list) {
var html = 
};
```

Please help me, I'm so lost. And if you could also please comment any code you give me, that would be so appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's that `target_dir`?

Comment: @AmitJoki Oh, I was just leaving that blank for now, because after I get all of this working, I will want to implement an onClick method for each list item.

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot to mention that, sorry!

Comment: But, you've accepted the answer. So, are you done with it? Is your problem solved?

Comment: I accepted it because it is helpful, but I am still working on it to see if I can apply what he said.

Comment: check out my answer too. I wanted to comment the code so that you could understand. So took me some time. There is a live demo too. But the images will not load, since you've got em ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
var contentList = [
{'content_title':'District 9', 'img_src':'district9.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Gladiator', 'img_src':'gladiator.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Django Unchained', 'img_src':'django.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Fantastic Mr. Fox', 'img_src':'fox.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
{'content_title':'Master and Commander', 'img_src':'master.jpg', 'target_dir':''}
];
var htmlStr = ''; // declare a variable which will hold the html for list
for(var i=0;i<contentList.length;i++) // create a loop to loop through contentList
{
   htmlStr += "<div><img src='"+contentList[i].img_src+"'/>"+contentList[i].content_title+"</div>";
}
document.getElementById('content-list').innerHTML = htmlStr; // assign the innerhtml
```

I've commented the code.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/bpGea/1/)

Comment: this worked :) thanks so much! I'm sure the other way works too, which I am still going to try and learn just so I can understand as much as possible. But this was the quickest fix.

Comment: but learn it. It will help you. Its lot easier than javascript, although it itself is a javascript library. Learn it at http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: haha, they are phenomenal creatures :) and sorry, I figured it was only JavaScript, but I'm still only just getting used to all of this. And I do intend on learning jQuery, soon enough... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

By the look of that `var html =`, I take it you're planning to build up a string of HTML code? I'm gonna assume you have your own plans on how to do that. It's mostly string concatenation, after all.

After you have `html` ready, use `document.getElementById` to get a reference to the container and set its `innerHTML` property to the string you've constructed.

```
document.getElementById('content-list').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Well, from the example I was looking at when I got to the var html =, I started to get lost because I didn't see where it was going. But that clears it up a bit and I will try doing that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
var contentList = [
    {'content_title':'District 9', 'img_src':'district9.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
    {'content_title':'Gladiator', 'img_src':'gladiator.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
    {'content_title':'Django Unchained', 'img_src':'django.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
    {'content_title':'Fantastic Mr. Fox', 'img_src':'fox.jpg', 'target_dir':''}, 
    {'content_title':'Master and Commander', 'img_src':'master.jpg', 'target_dir':''}
];

var myList = document.createElement("ul"); // create the list
for (var i = 0; i < contentList.length; i++) { // for each Object in your Array
    var myItem = document.createElement("li"); // create a item for the list
    var myAnchor = document.createElement("a"); // create an anchor for the target_dir property
    myAnchor.setAttribute("href", contentList[i].target_dir); // set the href attribute for the anchor

    var myTitle = document.createTextNode(contentList[i].content_title); // create the text node to be inside the anchor (from the content_title property)
    myAnchor.appendChild(myTitle); // append the text into the anchor

    var myImage = document.createElement("img"); // create the DOMElement for the image
    myImage.setAttribute("src", contentList[i].img_src); // set the attribute src (from the img_src property)
    myImage.setAttribute("alt", contentList[i].content_title); // set the alt attribute only cause it's required for both XHTML and HTML5

    myItem.appendChild(myAnchor); // append the anchor into the item list
    myItem.appendChild(myImage); // append the image into the item list

    myList.appendChild(myItem); // append the item list into the list
}

document.getElementById("content-list").appendChild(myList); // append the list into the div you've created
```

In jQuery:

```
var myList = $("<ul>")
for (var i = 0; i < contentList.length; i++) {
    var myItem = $("<li>");
    var myAnchor = $("<a>").attr("href", contentList[i].target_dir).text(contentList[i].content_title);
    var myImage = $("<img>").attr("src", contentList[i].img_src).attr("alt", contentList[i].content_title);

    myItem.append(myAnchor).append(myImage);
    myList.append(myItem);
}

$("#content-list").append(myList);
```

In "ugly" (String concatanation) Javascript:

```
var myHTML = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < contentList.length; i++) {
    myHTML += "<li><a href='" + contentList[i].target_dir + "'>" + contentList[i].content_title + "</a><img src='" + contentList[i].img_src + "' alt='" + contentList[i].content_title + "' /></li>";
}
myHTML += "</ul>"

document.getElementById("content-list").innerHTML = myHTML;
```

Comment: You guys are experts with this stuff. I don't how you are able to type up all this code so quickly. Thanks for all the help. I will try to understand each concept

Comment: Since Javascript works to modificate HTML/XHTML, I recommend you to always use the `document.createElement` and `appendChild` stuff, cause in this way, your HTML will never be broken, and when you start adding/removing items from your list, you'll see it's much easier and friendly =)

Comment: I've edited my post to comment the code, making it easier for you to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I will try to implement it your way as well, just so that I can expand my understanding. My only question is, if I wanted the images to be on the right-hand side of the  titles, while also removing the bullet points, would I do this in the css file? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah, you can remove the bullet using `list-style-type: none`, and you can change the place of your items changing the order you append them or if you prefer, using `float: left` / `float: right`. It's up to you ;)